# Solution for jQuery parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

look at my code here, please - https://jsfiddle.net/johndoe1994/xtu09zz9/

First of all, I'll tell you about its functionality

As you can see, there are two containers: `.first` and `.second`. In the `.first`, by default, I have another two divs. Both of them are `.item`. Class `.second`, by default, is empty.

If you hover each of `.item`, you could see bootstrap glyphicons - `heart`

If you click `.item`, it moves to `.second`. After that, if you hover `.item` on `.second`, heart glyphicon will change to `minus sign`

It looks good for me. But there is one very small problem with jQuery code

In my example, I click all `.item` container and this container clone() to `.second` (please, review my jQuery code). But in fact, I need to click only **glyphicon** and after this its `.item` container will **clone()** to `.second`

So, in other words, now I have this first line - `$(document).on('click', '.item', function()`
But I need something like that `$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-heart', function()`, as a first line

Can I do this with **parent()**? Or another jQuery method (**closest()**, **has()**)?

Help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make .gliphicon clickable, then select the .item and use in place of $(this) [jsfiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/xtu09zz9/2/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon', function() {
```

var item = $(this).closest(".item");

```
if(item.parent().attr("class") == "itemList") {
    item.clone().appendTo('.second');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    item.css({"opacity": "0.2", "-webkit-user-select": "none"});
}
else { //NEW ELSE
    var i = $('.itemList').find('[data-state="' + item.data('state') + '"]');

        i.css({"opacity": "1", "-webkit-user-select": "true"});
        i.find(".glyphicon").prop('disabled', false);

    item.remove();
}


});
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent()` works but is super fragile, it'll break at the slightest change in doc structure.  `$(this).closest('.item')` would be a lot safer.

Comment: @ST94 You wanted to create click event for the icon after the cloning happens. Right?

Comment: @silviagreen may I ask you another question? There is a little problem with your item.prop('disabled', true);. When I click .glyphicon-heart, I can add to the .right panel not only one this .item. So, I see, $(this).prop('disabled', true) is better solution

Comment: @silviagreen here is an updated *if* part - https://jsfiddle.net/johndoe1994/xtu09zz9/5/ but I still have problem with *else* part

Comment: @silviagreen here is your *else* - `$('.itemList').find('[data-state="' + item.data('state') + '"]').prop('disabled', false).css({"opacity": "1", "-webkit-user-select": "true"});`. It's almost good solution for me, but there is one moment - I need `.prop('disabled', false)` to `$(this)` glyphicon, not to all `item`

Answer (score 1):

Just set a `data-attribute` additionally, nothing more than that was changed with HTML. And event binding has been added for elements with class `glyphicon-minus-sign`

Also while removing the element, use `.closest('.item')` since, `$(this).remove()` will remove the icon.

Try to rewrite your logic like below,

**HTML**:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="itemList">
    <div class="item elem" data-state="loren">
      <div class="desc">Loren Ipsum Dolor</div>
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" data-state="loren"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item elem" data-state="sic">
      <div class="desc">Sic Amet</div>
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" data-state="sic"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.elem, .glyphicon-minus-sign', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).parent().attr("class") == "itemList") {
    $(this).removeClass("elem");
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.second');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).css({
      "opacity": "0.2",
      "-webkit-user-select": "none"
    });
  } else {
    $('.itemList')
      .find('div[data-state="' + $(this).data('state') + '"]')
      .prop('disabled', false)
      .css({
        "opacity": "1",
        "-webkit-user-select": "true"
      }).addClass("elem");
    $(this).closest('.item').remove();
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xtu09zz9/4/)

Comment: It's great answer, but there is still one little problem. I need same thing that you did not only for `.glyphicon-minus-sign`, but for `.glyphicon-heart` too. Only glyphicons can be clickable

Comment: You've created one half of what I need so much, thank you. Items located in `.second` now are moving to `.first` only on `.glyphicon-minus-sign` click. Same thing I need and for items with `.glyphicon-heart` located in the `.first`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following, using the parents selector, the father of your glyphicon is 'icons' and it's on the 0 position. So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".glyphicon").click(function() {
        if($(this).parents().eq(3).attr("class") == "itemList") {
          $(this).clone().appendTo('.second');
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          $(this).css({"opacity": "0.2", "-webkit-user-select": "none"});
        }
        else {
        $('.itemList')
          .find('[data-state="' + $(this).data('state') + '"]')
          .prop('disabled', false)
          .css({"opacity": "1", "-webkit-user-select": "true"});
        $(this).remove();
        }
   });
```

});